Discrepancy in Calculating Scalar and Sectional Curvature in 2D Geometry
I've been working on a problem related to curvature in two-dimensional geometries and found a discrepancy between my calculations of scalar and sectional curvature, which seems to contradict the known relationship that in 2D, the scalar curvature is twice the sectional curvature.
Here's the metric tensor for the geometry I'm considering:
$$ gM = (1 - (x^2 + y^2)) I_2 $$
Given that the metric is diagonal, I've calculated the following components:

The component of the Riemann curvature tensor:

$$ R_{1212} = \frac{2}{(1 - (x^2+y^2))^2} $$

The scalar curvature:

$$ R_{sc} = \frac{4}{(1 - (x^2+y^2))^3} $$
For the sectional curvature ( K ), using the formula:
$$ K = \frac{R(X,Y,Y,X)}{|X|^2|Y|^2 - g(X,Y)^2} $$
in this example $g(X,Y)=0$, so i obtained:
$$ K = \frac{2}{(1 - (x^2+y^2))^4} $$
Noticing that one denominator involves a cubic term and the other a quartic term, I suspect there might be an error in my calculations. Could anyone help identify where I might have gone wrong, or confirm if the discrepancy arises due to other reasons?
For reference, I found similar discussions here, but they do not cover the specific issue I'm encountering.
Thank you!

Update: I was really careless. I wrote $R_{1212}$ incorrectly here. The correct one should be $R_{1212} = \frac{2}{(1 - (x^2+y^2))}$.
By the way, is there an easier way to compute the scalar curvature and sectional curvature directly for metrics that are diagonal arrays, especially in high dimensions ($n>3$)?

Personally, I get $K=-2(1-r^2)^{-3}$, so there's lots to check.

@TedShifrin, Thank you! the non-zero component of the Riemann curvature tensor is $2(1-r^2)^{-2}$, and $g(x,x)=g(y,y)= (1-r^2)$, so i get $K= 2(1-r^2)^{-4}$. I know the correct result is $2(1-r^2)^{-3}$, but I don't know what's wrong from my calculation.

I lost track of a negative sign, so, yes, $2(1-r^2)^{-3}$ is correct. I personally recommend using differential forms and the method of moving frames. For a quick introduction for surfaces, see Section 3 of Chapter 3 of my free differential geometry text, linked in my profile.

@TedShifrin Thanks for the pointers and help! I will go and read up on your recommend textbook, thanks again for your selfless help!
